# Gson custom deserializer not called for null values

Tags: java, gson, deserialization

I'm using Gson serialization in a JavaFX context. To avoid having property boilerplate in my serialized Json, I created a handful of custom serializers/deserializers to write the property's value instead of the actual property object, in particular this one for the generic `Property<T>`:

```
private static class PropertySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Property<?>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Property<?> property, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Object value = property.getValue();
        return context.serialize(value);
    }
}

private static class PropertyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Property<?>> {
    @Override
    public Property<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonNull()) {
            System.out.println("I am never printed");
        }
        Type typeParam = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Object obj = context.deserialize(json, typeParam);
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(obj);
    }
}
```

It worked pretty well until I stumbled upon null values. By design, when the property's value is null (not the property itself), my serializer will write a null because it writes the value, not the property (I have used `Gson.serializeNulls()` to make it actually write it).

My problem is that, at deserialization time, **my custom serializer is not called for null values** because of [a Gson bug](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/171) caused by these lines in `com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter`:

```
@Override public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (deserializer == null) {
        return delegate().read(in);
    }
    JsonElement value = Streams.parse(in);
    if (value.isJsonNull()) {
        return null; // bypasses my custom deserializer! Why you do dat to me?
    }
    return deserializer.deserialize(value, typeToken.getType(), gson.deserializationContext);
}
```

This **results in the property itself being null** after deserialization instead of a non-null property containing a null value.

---

They marked the bug as fixed because apparently there is a workaround using a `TypeAdapterFactory`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. It looks like I have to manually deserialize the object, but I don't know its type so I can't. The `TypeAdapter` methods `read` and `write` don't provide me with the `JsonDeserializationContext` of my current `Gson`, so I can't rely on its standard deserialization for my value (which I did very easily with the custom deserializer).

```
private static class PropertyTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Property<?>> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Property<?> value) throws IOException {
        Object valueToSerialize = value.getValue();
        // how to use standard serialization of my object?
    }

    @Override
    public Property<?> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        switch (in.peek()) {
            case NULL:
                return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
            default:
                Type typeOfT = ???
                Type typeParam = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                return ???; // how to invoke standard deserialization of my object?
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers:
I didn't like the solution I implemented at first in my other answer, so I changed it to use `TypeAdapter` instead of a custom deserializer.

This takes more code to write, so I ended up writing a lightweight library tailored to use Gson in the context of JavaFX, so that no one has to write it again :)

Here it is: [FxGson](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-gson).

Comment: Hi, my TypeAdapter's (provided by my TypeAdapterFactory) read method doesn't get called for null values. And I can't find a proper way to force it to deserialize nulls. How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy usually they are called for nulls, but I don't think they are called if the property is missing in the json. Have you enabled "serializeNulls" on your Gson?

Comment: As far as I found out `serializeNulls()` doesn't affect deserialization. Also, neither custom deserializers, nor custom TypeAdapters are invoked upon null fields. Source: I debugged a lot last two days; also: see comment here - https://github.com/google/gson/issues/948

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy Sorry for being unclear, I was just assuming you were deserializing your own serialization. My point was rather, "are you trying to deserialize a null value or a missing field?". That being said, what you found is very strange, because the Gson guys actually told me at the time to use a TypeAdapter instead of a Deserializer especially to be passed null values.

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy FYI [this is where](https://github.com/google/gson/pull/852#issuecomment-218432588) I was told to use a `TypeAdapter`. The issue I was trying to fix with the PR is [this one](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/171). Maybe your problem lies in your `TypeAdapterFactory`?

Comment: I guess I actually used the example given by JakeWharton from the first thread you linked (the code is almost the same), but `read()` method never gets called when actual JSON value is null. If it is any other value it works just fine, my TypeAdapter method gets called.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, my team decided to go the other way to handle this issue. Maybe I'll post a separate and properly worded SO question later when I have free time. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy No worries. I'd be interested to know your final approach when you have time. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, I used a simple workaround: I serialize my property to a specific String "null" whenever the content of the property is null. I take that into account for deserialization and everything works fine.

Here is my code:

```
private static class PropertySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Property<?>>, JsonDeserializer<Property<?>> {

    private static final String NULL_PLACEHOLDER = "null";

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Property<?> property, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Object value = property.getValue();
        return context.serialize(value != null ? value : NULL_PLACEHOLDER);
    }

    @Override
    public Property<?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (isNullPlaceholder(json)) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
        }
        Type typeParam = ((ParameterizedType) typeOfT).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        Object obj = context.deserialize(json, typeParam);
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(obj);
    }

    private static boolean isNullPlaceholder(JsonElement json) {
        try {
            return json.isJsonPrimitive() && NULL_PLACEHOLDER.equals(json.getAsString());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            return false; // not a string, so definitely not the placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

### Potential issue

There is one problem with this approach, if the Property is a `Property<String>` and its value is actually "null" (or whatever you choose as placeholder).

However, this should not be an issue because people should use `StringProperty` instead of `Property<String>`, which will go through its own serializer anyway.

<del>You can find [my full `FxGson` class on Github](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-log/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hildan/fxlog/config/FxGson.java).</del>
*Edit: this class doesn't exist anymore as I created [FxGson with TypeAdapters](https://github.com/joffrey-bion/fx-gson)*